# html javascript having 2 div's side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

i've got 2 `div's`, one to display a map and the other `form-horizontal` to display `textboxes`. currently the map is showing at the top of the page and the `textboxes` at the bottom. is it possible to display the `textboxes` at the `left` and the map `right` beside in to the right?

```
<div itemprop="map" id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
<div class="form-horizontal"></div>
```

Comment: Remove the "width: 100%" property and use float:left and float:right to align respectively left and right

Answer (score 1):

Without anymore CSS that you have used, all I can say is that the CSS property, `display:inline-block;`, should work on these elements to make them display on the same line.

Make sure you remove the `width:100%;` property from the first div, too.

Comment: really? if your going to edit my question to "improve" it don't just change letters to capitals.

Comment: everything is spelt correctly, you we're changing small letters into capitals. quite pointless and a waste of time if you ask me.

Comment: @userdanhas1994 Improving readability is not pointless. I'm afraid to imagine what your code might look like if you're unable to follow such a well established standard in writing English.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float`:

**CSS:**

```
#googleMap {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.form-horizontal {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div itemprop="map" id="googleMap"></div>
<div class="form-horizontal"></div>
```